# numpy: bitwise and on array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to do an "&" operation across all the values in a simple bool array.  The array I have is as follows:

```
array([False False True], dtype=bool)
```

The only thing I've come up with is to slice out the values in the array and use "&" to give a "False" result.  I feel like there must be a better way but I don't know enough about numpy to use it properly.

Comment: Just FYI, this operation is not bitwise in memory, but rather bytewise, since boolean variables take up a full byte each :/. You can do true bitwise operations on e.g. `np.uint8` variables however using the operators `&, |, <<, >>` if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arr.all()`, which is the same as [`np.all(arr)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([False, False, True], dtype=bool) 
arr.all()
=> False
np.all(arr)
=> False
```

Comment: For completeness, the converse of `np.all` is `np.any`.